# VLC symbolic icon not working

Tags: 18.04, icon-themes

I am using Papirus icon theme. I successfully added a 16x16 `thunderbird-symbolic.svg` image to the `symbolic` folder. But when I do the same with `vlc-symbolic.svg`, it still shows a colourful icon on the top panel. Is it hard coded ? Is there any method using which we can change this ?

I have a fully updated 18.04. VLC version is 3.0.7.

Update 1 :

This is what I see now

[image]

I would like to replace the icon in panel using  vlc-symbolic.svg

I am not able to upload SVG here. On Google Drive as zip file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NXdUHiX_IgsACf0bku4QKLYsaZNJyAQo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101705/discussion-on-question-by-user227495-vlc-symbolic-icon-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3
VLC: snap install

Please note that, for clarity purpose I have deleted all the default icon themes every where and used Only Papirus Icon theme.

***Workaround***

seems to be gschemas compiled in both `~/snap/vlc/1049/.local/share/...` and in `/snap/vlc/1049/usr/share...` directorys are for `Adwaita` Icon theme.

I have made several trails for almost 4 days and found that below workaround may be useful.

1. Create a Directory `Adwaita` with `index.theme` file in it, containing below data in `$HOME/snap/vlc/1049/.local/share/` Directory.

Content:

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=Adwaita
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. Place your `Papirus` Icon-theme folder under `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/icons/` directory.

for clear understanding I have deleted every icon named `vlc-panel.*` in Papirus theme and placed my custom svg icon with name `vlc-panel.svg` under `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/icons/Papirus/symbolic/status/`